# Has anyone run spark-submit recently?

Tags: spark-submit

I am getting the below error while running spark-submit. Any help is appreciated.

```
20/05/30 10:27:32 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
```

THanks,
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

Try setting you file path

```
"file\\C:\path to the file\"
```

instead of

```
"C:\path to the file\"
```